# Python-Parmiko Error: 'RSAKey' object is not iterable'

Tags: python, ssh, rsa, paramiko, openssh

I created a RSA key pair via `sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` and copied to the `.ssh` folder. I am using the Python paramiko package. My code is:

```
import paramiko
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa', password='mypassphrase')
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
conn = s.connect('remote_computer', username ='username', port=22, key_filename =k)
command = 'sudo python ~/pythonscript.py'
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = s.exec_command(command)
s.close()
```

But when I try to run the code, I am getting the following error and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pythonparamikoscript.py", line 6, in <module>
conn = s.connect('remote_computer', username ='username', port=22, key_filename =k)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 307, in connect
look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 441, in _auth
for key_filename in key_filenames:
TypeError: 'RSAKey' object is not iterable
```

Help is appreciated, since this leaves me desperate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[connect()](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/client.html) accepts different arguments:

- `pkey (PKey)` which is the place where you should assign your key
- `key_filename (str)` which is just a string with a location of your key.

So running

```
conn = s.connect('remote_computer', username ='username', port=22, pkey=k)
```

should do the job.

Comment: @MrMeeseeks If this solved your issue, you should mark this answer as a solution.